# Entity Framework 6 tenta inserir FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf

Tenho uma pequena aplicação em C#, WPF e EF6.

Estou usando *Code First*, mas estou com dificuldade para criar um relacionamento. Vejam meu código, das classes que quero relacionar:
Estou editando para a versão final, caso alguém tenha a mesma duvida.

```
public class Caixa
{
    [Key]
    public int CaixaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFechamento { get; set; }
    public Boolean Aberto { get; set; }
    public Decimal Troco { get; set; }
    public Decimal TotalRetiradas { get; set; }
    public Decimal TotalEntradas { get; set; }
    public Decimal Total { get; set; }
    public Decimal TotalEmCaixa { get; set; }
    public String Observacoes { get; set; }
    public Usuario Responsavel { get; set; }        

    public Caixa()
    {
        DataAbertura = DateTime.Now;
    }

}

public class Usuario
{
    [Key]    
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }        
    [Required, Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public String Login { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public Boolean Administrador { get; set; }

}

 public class Contexts: DbContext
{
    //entidades
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Caixa> Caixas { get; set; }

    public Contexts()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Contexts>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {    

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);            
    }

}
```

O codigo que salva é o seguinte:

```
database.Caixas.Add(NovoCaixa);
NovoCaixa.Responsavel = database.Usuarios.Single(u => u.UsuarioId == UsuarioAtivo.UsuarioId);
database.SaveChanges();
```

Sempre que tento salvar a entidade Caixa, me veem este erro:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = Usuario, Constraint name = IX_Login ]
```

Desconfio que ele está tentanto inserir o usuario, porém não é o que quero, pois ele já existe.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou fazendo esse projeto para aprender o EF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possivelmente você criou o *Model* `Usuario`, inseriu dois usuários com o mesmo `Login` e tentou executar uma *Migration* pra obter o erro.

Reverta todas as *Migrations* usando um dos dois comandos:

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
```

Ou

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:$InitialDatabase
```

Depois disso, apague todas as *Migrations* e gere outra *Migration*. Execute mais um `Update-Database`.

---

**EDIT**

Você está usando errado `AddOrUpdate`. Desta forma, a configuração sempre tenta inserir um `Usuario`, não importando se ele existe ou não.

A maneira correta é:

```
database.Caixas.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Login, caixa); 
database.SaveChanges();
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Basicamente, está **tudo** errado na sua solução.

Você não precisa implementar uma DAL (não DAO, porque DAL é o nome da camada, *Database Abstraction Layer*, e DAO é o objeto em si, *Database Abstraction Object*). O Entity Framework já implementa completamente uma DAL, então você não precisa reinventar a roda.

Possivelmente você quer isolar a lógica em uma camada de serviço, mas o WPF é um padrão MVVM, em que basicamente é a tela que realiza a persistência dos objetos, então é melhor desistir de isolar qualquer coisa até que seja bem entendido como o Entity Framework funciona.

Como eu disse, não é assim que se persiste um objeto na base:

```
database.Caixas.AddOrUpdate(caixa);
database.Entry(caixa).Property("ResponsavelId").EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
database.SaveChanges();
```

`AddOrUpdate` **não é um comando para operações rotineiras**. Ele é um comando pra você fazer inserções iniciais para o seu sistema funcionar (prática também conhecida como "semear a base"). É mais comum em projetos Web, sobretudo usando ASP.NET MVC.

Para inserir um novo objeto, o comando correto é:

```
database.Caixas.Add(caixa);
```

Para atualizar:

```
database.Entry(caixa).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Não tente fazer um método para realizar as duas operações. O Entity Framework não funciona bem assim. Ainda assim, se você realmente quer usar apenas um código para realizar as duas operações (o que não tem necessidade), você pode conferir se a chave do objeto está nula:

```
if (caixa.CaixaId == null) 
{
    database.Caixas.Add(caixa);
} else 
{
    database.Entry(caixa).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

database.SaveChanges();
```

Note o absurdo do código abaixo:

```
database.Entry(caixa).Property("ResponsavelId").EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Você está pegando uma propriedade de navegação e tentando dizer ao contexto que ela não foi modificada, mas está inserindo um novo `Caixa` com um `Responsavel` pendurado na entidade. O Entity Framework interpreta este `Responsavel` como um objeto novo. Por mais que você diga que este `Responsavel` não é um novo objeto, o Entity Framework entende que é porque `Caixa` é um objeto novo. Por isso seu erro.

Não sei como você está fazendo pra criar este `Caixa`, mas as duas maneiras corretas e mais comuns são:

- Criando o objeto e definindo um `Responsavel`, selecionando o `Responsavel` se isto for necessário;
- Recebendo um `Caixa` preenchido por uma tela e enviado para o código que contém o `DbContext`.

Para o seu caso, que está em WPF, a primeira forma possivelmente é a mais provável para este cenário. Ou seja, a criação de um `Caixa` deve ser assim:

```
var responsavel = database.Usuarios.Single(/* Coloque aqui a condição para selecionar um Responsavel */); 
var caixa = new Caixa 
{
    Responsavel = responsavel
    /* Não defina ResponsavelId. O Entity Framework deduz ResponsavelId porque você já preencheu o Responsavel */
    /* Preencha aqui as demais properties */
};

databases.Caixas.Add(caixa);
databases.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já fiz e não deu certo. O que me veem a mente é que no momento de salvar, ele está inserindo a instância de Usuario como uma nova tupla, ocasionando o erro. Faz sentido esse pensamento?

Comment: Faz. Como você está fazendo pra salvar?

Comment: database.Caixas.AddOrUpdate(caixa);                
database.SaveChanges();
databse herda de context e tem todos os DbSet do sistema

Comment: @ViniciusMaboni Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não deu certo amigão. Na verdade eu quero que o caixa seja sempre inserido como novo, mas o usuário é quem deve existir previamente. Seguindo sua sugestão, ele insere um caixa novo para cada Id de usuario, assim não mantém o historico de que preciso.

Comment: Não. Segundo minha sugestão, o `Caixa` é inserido apenas se outro `Caixa` com o mesmo nome não existir. Se existir, ele atualiza o registro de caixa que tem o nome correspondente. É como chamar um `update` no SQL.

Comment: Qual o código que você usa para inserir um novo `Usuario`?

Comment: Não é isso que preciso. Preciso que, se existir ele crie do mesmo jeito, porém o caixa com id diferente. Nada impede um usuario de abrir varios caixas, é uma relação one-to-many. O codigo onde faço a inserção é bem simples:

        database.Caixas.AddOrUpdate(caixa);                
        database.SaveChanges();

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta e coloque os códigos lá.

Comment: @ViniciusMaboni Fiz mais uma edição na resposta.

Comment: Uau! Que aula amigão! Muito obrigado. Acho que eu estava misturando padrões na minha cabeça, não é? 
Vou reimplementar meu código todo seguindo suas sugestões. Muito obrigado.